# how to fix this "Function created with compilation errors"

Tags: function, plsql

```sql
Create or replace FUNCTION invoice_total_price_function
    (p_invoice_num IN invoice_line.invoice_num%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    v_price book.price%TYPE :=0;
    v_order_quantity invoice_line.order_quantity%TYPE :=0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT price, order_quantity
        INTO v_price, v_order_quantity
        FROM book, invoice_line
        WHERE book.isbn_code = invoice_num.isbn_code
        AND invoice_num = p_invoice_num;
        RETURN SUM(v_price * v_order_quantity);
    END invoice_total_price_function;
```

hoping to find out the total price of all the invoice line into a single invoice.
how can i see which line i should be edited? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `SUM` is out of place. If you want aggregation of multiple rows - do it in your query.
2. Don't use implicit joins. Use ANSI join.

Your final function should look something like this:

```sql
Create or replace FUNCTION invoice_total_price_function
    (p_invoice_num IN invoice_line.invoice_num%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    v_total_price NUMBER :=0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT SUM(price * order_quantity)
        INTO v_total_price
        FROM book
        JOIN invoice_line on (isbn_code = invoice_num.isbn_code)
        WHERE invoice_num = p_invoice_num;

        RETURN v_total_price;
    END invoice_total_price_function;
```

Please note, that here I assumed that type of `v_total_price` would be NUMBER (since that's what functions designed to return), but you should check and suite it to your needs.